# Tengo un fatal error en esta linea n1 = int.Parse(h);

Tags: c#

```
n1 = int.Parse(h);
```

Estaba en mi tarea copiando y pegando elementos repetidos cuando el programa señaló esta linea como fatal error diciendo que el valor no puede ser nulo  o sea no registra el valor es una mayúscula:

```
int n1, n2, n3;
string h;
        
Console.WriteLine("numero 1");

h = Console.ReadLine();
n1 = int.Parse(h);
```

Comment: El código está bien, pudo haberte tirado nulo si hubieras presionado enter. Si ingresas una mayúscula te dará un error de formato

Comment: Lecturas recomendadas: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=net-6.0 + https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-6.0 :D